# Problems in Cylinder Vibration Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am a beginner with MMA. I want to solve dynamic differential equations with cylinder shells. I have tried to input the equations and solve them using finite difference and NDSolve, but I can't get the correct result. For the convenience of FEM, there is little material concerning solutions with cylinder shells. And I can't use FEM for my research goal. So I want to find some help here.
[image]
Here are the cylinder equations, which are called "Flugge cylinder shell equations".

[image: Differential equations of cylinder shell]

Where $u$, $v$, $w$ are the displacement; $R$ is the diameter of cylinder shells; $υ$ is Poisson's ratio; $h$ is the thickness of shells; and $k = (h/R)^2/12$.

Here are the boundary conditions, which means the two ends of shell are simpled supported.

$$
v\left( 0,\theta ,t \right) =0,w\left( 0,\theta ,t \right) ,v\left( L,\theta ,t \right) =0,w\left( L,\theta ,t \right) $$
$$
N_x\left( 0,\theta ,t \right) =0,M_x\left( 0,\theta ,t \right) ,N_x\left( L,\theta ,t \right) =0,M_x\left( L,\theta ,t \right) 
$$
$$
N_x=K\left[ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\nu \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}+\frac{w}{R} \right) \right] ,M_x=D\left[ \frac{\partial ^2w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\nu}{R^2}\left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial ^2w}{\partial \theta ^2} \right) \right] 
$$

Here is the code I’ve tried.

```
\[Rho] = 1; 
\[Nu] = 0.3; 
h = 2/31; 
\[Rho]s = 8; 
ms = \[Rho]s*h; 
E0 = 99.63; 
R = 1; 
c = 1; 
l = 1; 
te = 5; 
We = 20; 
rd = 50; 
p0 = 1; 
q = c/R; 
Pinc[t_] := p0*Exp[(-q)*t]; 
\[Theta]i = 0; 
a = 2*R; 
d = (rd^2 + 2*rd*a*Cos[\[Theta]i])/(Sqrt[rd^2 + a^2 + 2*rd*a*Cos[\[Theta]i]] + a); 
b0 = 1./d + a/2; 
b = Sqrt[b0^2 + 4.*a*(a - b0)*Sin[\[Theta]i/2]^2]; 
\[Beta] = ArcCos[(b0 + 2.*(a - b0)*Sin[\[Theta]i/2]^2)/b]; 
Psat[t_] = (Pinc[t] - c*(1/b - 1/rd)*Exp[((-c)*t)/b]*Integrate[Exp[(c*t)/b]*Pinc[t], t])*(Cos[\[Theta]i]/Cos[\[Beta]]); 
qz[t_] := Pinc[t] + Psat[t]; 

k = (h/R)^2/12; 
e1l = R^2*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}] + ((1 - \[Nu])/2)*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], {\[Theta], 2}] + (R/2)*(1 + \[Nu])*D[v[x, \[Theta], t], x, \[Theta]] - 
    \[Nu]*R*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], x] + k*(((1 - \[Nu])/2)*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], {\[Theta], 2}] + R^3*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 3}] - 
      (R/2)*(1 - \[Nu])*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], x, {\[Theta], 2}]); 
e1r = (((1 - \[Nu]^2)*R^2)/(E0*h))*(\[Rho]s*h*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], {t, 2}]); 
e2l = (R/2)*(1 + \[Nu])*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], x, \[Theta]] + (R^2/2)*(1 - \[Nu])*D[v[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}] + D[v[x, \[Theta], t], {\[Theta], 2}] - 
    D[w[x, \[Theta], t], \[Theta]] + k*((3/2)*(1 - \[Nu])*D[v[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}] + (R^2/2)*(3 - \[Nu])*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}, \[Theta]]); 
e2r = (((1 - \[Nu]^2)*R^2)/(E0*h))*(\[Rho]s*h*D[v[x, \[Theta], t], {t, 2}]); 
e3l = \[Nu]*R*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], x] + D[v[x, \[Theta], t], \[Theta]] - w[x, \[Theta], t] - 
    k*(R^4*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 4}] + 2*R^2*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}, {\[Theta], 2}] + D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {\[Theta], 4}]) + 
    k*((-R^3)*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 3}] + (R/2)*(1 - \[Nu])*D[u[x, \[Theta], t], x, {\[Theta], 2}] - 
      (R^2/2)*(3 - \[Nu])*D[v[x, \[Theta], t], {x, 2}, \[Theta]] - w[x, \[Theta], t] - 2*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {\[Theta], 2}]); 
e3r = (((1 - \[Nu]^2)*R^2)/(E0*h))*(\[Rho]s*h*D[w[x, \[Theta], t], {t, 2}] - qz[t]); 

var = {u[x, \[Theta], t], v[x, \[Theta], t], w[x, \[Theta], t]}; 
pde = {e1l == e1r, e2l == e2r, e3l == e3r}; 
ics = {Thread[var == {0, 0, 0}], Thread[D[var, t] == {0, 0, 0}]} /. t -> 0; 
bcs1 = {u[x, 0, t] == u[x, 2*Pi, t], v[x, 0, t] == v[x, 2*Pi, t], w[x, 0, t] == w[x, 2*Pi, t]}; 
  bcs2 = Thread[{v[x, \[Theta], t], w[x, \[Theta], t]} == {0, 0}] /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> l}}; bcs3 = Thread[D[var, {x, 2}] == {0, 0, 0}]; 
bcs = Flatten[{bcs1, bcs2, bcs3}]; 
rs = Apply[Set, Flatten[NDSolve[{pde, bcs, ics}, {u, v, w}, {t, 0, te}, {x, 0, l}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]], {1}]
```

The error in trying this program is that the equation is overdetermined. I think there is a problem with the boundary conditions, but I don't know how to modify them.

Thank you to everyone who has seen and answered, and wish you a merry Christmas in advance.

Comment: Please read [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good in this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) and, following the instructions there, edit your question with readable code. Additionally, what is your specific question? It seems that you just want someone else to do this for you...

Comment: Your advice was so useful that I thought I had made a change， thanks.

Comment: 1. Please provide a minimal sample illustrating the problem, this site isn't a free debugging service. 2. `bcs3` is obviously wrong. 3. What's the relationship between $u,v,w$ and $V,W, N_x^*, M_x^*$?